# OUTPUT Parameters of stored procedure returns only one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables in SQL Server :

Table A

```
ID Num
11 tj55
4  tj40
```

Table B

```
ID NUM A_ID
3 se400 4
5 se500 4
```

I want to create a stored procedure which will return for each row in A all corresponding rows in B, I want to have this result

```
NumA NumB
tj40 se400
tj40 se500
```

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] 
    @param nvarchar(MAX),
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        aa.Num,
        bb.Num
    FROM 
        [dbo].[A]  as aa
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[B] AS bb ON bb.A_ID = aa.ID 
    WHERE 
        aa.Num = @param
    ORDER BY 
        aa.Num
 END
```

This stored procedure works fine and returns exactly what I need but when I add the `OUTPUT` parameters (which I need)

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc] 
    @param nvarchar(MAX),
    @RET1 varchar(MAX) OUTPUT,
    @RET2 nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
 AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT 
       @RET1= aa.Num,
       @RET2 = bb.Num
    FROM 
       [dbo].[A]  as aa
    INNER JOIN 
       [dbo].[B] AS bb ON bb.A_ID = aa.ID 
    WHERE 
       aa.Num = @param
    ORDER BY 
       aa.Num
END
```

I have only one row as result

```
NumA NumB
tj40 se400
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you want to add output variables? To name the columns? Try it without stating `OUTPUT`

Comment: It's probably related with the output parameter returns a single value.
You can try assign the value to the output parameter in a statement and the other values you want from select in another statement, with two selects.

Comment: Your output is a scalar value; it, by definition cannot return more than one value

Comment: why not just select the values?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'm using Output because I need it to use Stored Procedures with JPA!

Comment: @Learthgz - by **far** the most common way for a stored procedure to return multiple results is for it to just produce result set(s), as your first example does. If you haven't found a way to consume such result sets through JPA, I'd suggest you look a bit harder. I'm 100% sure that it supports reading result sets from stored procedures and yet I've never even looked at the technology.

Answer (score 1):

A stored procedure only returns scalar values, not rows.  It will print the results of a query, but a user-defined inline table function is better:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ProcFunc] (
    @param nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (SELECT aa.Num, bb.Num
        FROM [dbo].[A] aa INNER JOIN
             [dbo].[B] bb
             ON bb.A_ID = aa.ID 
        WHERE aa.Num = @param
        ORDER BY aa.Num
       );
```

You can then call it as:

```
select *
from dbo.ProcFunc('abc');
```